# How to extract Hour (in UTC time) from datetime

Tags: r, time

Given the local time `fromLocalTime` and the `state` I want to create a column titled `hourUTC` that returns the hour only (in UTC time)

So given the data:

```
> dput(head(smart1,10))
structure(list(fromLocalTime = structure(c(1567086360, 1567604820, 
1568037120, 1571344680, 1565797140, 1568641740, 1565983980, 1567100520, 
1569963060, 1563888180), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    state = c("GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", 
    "TX", "FL")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
> data.frame(smart1)
         fromLocalTime state
1  2019-08-29 09:46:00    GA
2  2019-09-04 09:47:00    GA
3  2019-09-09 09:52:00    GA
4  2019-10-17 16:38:00    GA
5  2019-08-14 11:39:00    TX
6  2019-09-16 09:49:00    TX
7  2019-08-16 15:33:00    TX
8  2019-08-29 13:42:00    TX
9  2019-10-01 16:51:00    TX
10 2019-07-23 09:23:00    FL
```

I want an output like this:

```
> data.frame(smart1)
         fromLocalTime state hourUTC
1  2019-08-29 09:46:00    GA      13
2  2019-09-04 09:47:00    GA      13
3  2019-09-09 09:52:00    GA      13
4  2019-10-17 16:38:00    GA      20
5  2019-08-14 11:39:00    TX      16
6  2019-09-16 09:49:00    TX      14
7  2019-08-16 15:33:00    TX      20
8  2019-08-29 13:42:00    TX      18
9  2019-10-01 16:51:00    TX      21
10 2019-07-23 09:23:00    FL      13
```

In excel, I use this formula to get timezone based on state. I know this is not all encompassing but for my data, it will suffice:
=if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"WA,OR,CA,NV")),"Pacific",if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"MT,ID,WY,UT,CO,AZ,NM")),"Mountain",if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"ND,SD,NE,KS,OK,TX,MN,IA,MO,AR,LA,WI,IL,TN,MS,AL")),"Central",if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"MI,IN,OH,PA,NY,VT,ME,NH,MA,RI,CT,KY,NJ,DE,MD,WV,VA,NC,SC,GA,FL,DC")),"Eastern",if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"AK")),"Alaska",if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"HI")),"Hawaii",""))))))

Comment: Time zones aren't determined by state. Places like Kentucky have two different time zones. You can't uniquely convert to UTC with just that information. You'd have to build your own table of how many hours you want to shift the time for each state.

Comment: @MrFlick very true I suppose. I will update the question with the excel formula I use to "generally" get most of each state from this website https://alexsappsdev.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-convert-state-to-timezone-using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your provided table, if you are just trying to approximate (and not worry about daylight savings time), you could do something like

```
smart1 %>% mutate(
  approxUTC = lubridate::hour(fromLocalTime) + case_when(
      state %in% c("WA","OR","CA","NV")~8,
      state %in% c("MT","ID","WY","UT","CO","AZ","NM")~7,
      state %in% c("ND","SD","NE","KS","OK","TX","MN","IA","MO","AR","LA","WI","IL","TN","MS","AL")~6,
      state %in% c("MI","IN","OH","PA","NY","VT","ME","NH","MA","RI","CT","KY","NJ","DE","MD","WV","VA","NC","SC","GA","FL","DC")~5,
      state %in% c("AK")~9,
      state %in% c("HI")~10,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```